# Change date from dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, vba

i have an issue when changing the dates from dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS to dd/mm/yyyy not all dates change into the correct format.

An example of my issue

```
Column E
03-10-2019 36:12:50
10/03/2010
10/03/2010
10/03/2010
03-10-2019
```

The code i used for its neighbour was this:

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells
.TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" 
End With
```

All the dates in Column D change to dd/mm/yyyy....

This the code i made to copy the data from the .txt files

```
myBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set nav = CreateObject("shell.application")
folder = nav.browseforfolder(0, "PICK FOLDER", 0, "c:\").items.Item.Path
ChDir folder & "\"
file = Dir("*.txt")
Do While file <> ""

Workbooks.OpenText file, origin:=xlWindows, startrow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlTextFormat), Array(2, xlTextFormat), Array(3, xlTextFormat), Array(4, xlTextFormat), Array(5, xlTextFormat), Array(6, xlTextFormat), Array(7, xlTextFormat), Array(8, xlTextFormat), Array(9, xlTextFormat), Array(10, xlTextFormat))
```

Comment: What code do you get when you use the macro recorder?

Comment: Range("E2:E138").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"  @RossSymonds

Comment: Could you use the code Range("E2:E" & cells(rows.count,5).end(xlUp).row).numberformat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: Some dates change and other stay as dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss, i copy this data from a .txt file, cause im trying to automate the report making, i set the all the cells to text before i copy/paste the data onto the excel @RossSymonds

Comment: Your data input method is causing your problem. Instead of copying the data from the text file, you should **Import** it.  At the time of importation, you specify the date format used in the text file.  Then your dates will wind up as "real" Excel dates, and you can change the format in Excel using the cell.numberformat property.

Comment: I understand what you say but i don't know where to apply it, gotta show you my whole code cause i think what you're saying to me is already done but gotta change something and i don't know what to @RonRosenfeld

Comment: You can probably just show the part of the code where you transfer your text file to your Excel worksheet.  Or you can **Import** the file with the macro recorder running, and then modify that.

Comment: I edited the question so my code is up, you should see it by now @RonRosenfeld

Comment: I believe you want to use xlDMYFormat instead of xlTextFormat, for that particular column in your array

Comment: Set the format for the date column to xldmyformat, and be aware that the time will be in a separate column if you are using space for the delimiter. You should explicitly set the delimiters, else they will default to the last used.